# Gene Roddenberry and "Star Trek: The Motion Picture"

Tags: star-trek, gene-roddenberry, star-trek-the-motion-picture

In Roddenberry's novelization *Star Trek: The Motion Picture 40th Anniversary Edition* there are some curious items that are added that I don't recall in the film or the series:

Page 1: Starfleet apparently use an implant called a "senceiver" that is used to transmit messages in only the most urgent of emergencies.

Page 1: Footnote refers to the Mind Control Revolt of 2043-47.

Page 27: The first of two references to *New Humans amongst the Earth's population*, the other on page 98.

Page 84: Details of alien explorers on Io and the Moon. In particular, evidence found on the Moon suggested that the aliens had conducted genetic experiments with Earth's early life forms millions of years ago.

These seem rather weird things to include and I don't recall any vaguely similar ideas mooted in the *Star Trek* franchise.

Were any of these ideas used in any other Roddenberry series?

Comment: The lunar reference sounds like a hat tip to *2001*.

Comment: I don't have my copy to hand, but as I recall, most, if not all, that material was in the original edition of the novelization.  Some of it ("the New Humans") was (I think) intended to explain why Kirk and his crew seemed so old-fashioned (because they were old-fashioned, compared to the majority of humans).

Comment: How the heck did Roddenberry publish a "40th anniversary edition" when he died 22 years after *The Motion Picture* first aired?

Comment: @Lexible well I'm sure editions don't need authors to still be alive.  As the text is likely the same from the original 1979 version.   While the internet seems to now lean to Gene being the author I'm skeptical and suspect Alan Dean Foster ghost wrote?  And he's thankfully alive.

Comment: I suppose you could retcon the dinosaur Voth from Voyager to be the mysterious aliens leaving evidence on the moon.  The senciever is notable because unlike the movie Spock is aware of V'ger because he's telepathically linked to Kirk.  There's a trend to pretend Trek is more advanced than it really was.  Like saying TOS had 3D viewscreens.  Likewise you can't disprove any transhumanist implants despite how luddite Trek really is.  But technically your question is limited largely to Genesis II and the Questor Tapes and I'm not aware of any similar ideas to what you mentioned.